# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" (found in <Root>)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a new Vue project using Vue CLI. I changed `App.vue` as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    App.vue
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { populateTestData } from "./js/testData";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  mixins: [populateTestData],
  methods: {
    init() {
      this.populateTestData();
    },
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.init();
  },
};
</script>
```

testData.js:

```js
function populateTestData() {
  console.log("populateTestData")
}
export { populateTestData };
```

When I execute this with **npm run build**, I get the following error message:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at normalizeProps (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1419)
    at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1521)
    at mergeOptions (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1535)
    at Function.Vue.extend (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5159)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3184)
    at _createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3434)
    at createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3353)
    at vm.$createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3494)
    at Proxy.render (main.js?56d7:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

`testData.js` does not correctly define a [Vue mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). To define a method mixin to be exported, you'd export an object with a `methods` prop that contains your desired method (much like declaring a new component options with object syntax):

```js
// ./js/testData.js
export default {
  methods: {
    populateTestData() {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

Then your component would use the mixin like this:

```js
import myMixin from './js/testData'

export default {
  mixins: [myMixin],
}
```